# Kotlin secondary constructor

Tags: syntax, constructor, kotlin

How do I declare a secondary constructor in Kotlin?

Is there any documentation about that?

Following does not compile...

```
class C(a : Int) {
  // Secondary constructor
  this(s : String) : this(s.length) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**Update**: Since M11 (0.11.*) Kotlin supports [*secondary constructors*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors).

---

For now Kotlin supports only primary constructors (secondary constructors may be supported later).

Most use cases for secondary constructors are solved by one of the techniques below:

**Technique 1.** (solves your case) Define a factory method next to your class

```
fun C(s: String) = C(s.length)
class C(a: Int) { ... }
```

usage:

```
val c1 = C(1) // constructor
val c2 = C("str") // factory method
```

**Technique 2.** (may also be useful) Define default values for parameters

```
class C(name: String? = null) {...}
```

usage:

```
val c1 = C("foo") // parameter passed explicitly
val c2 = C() // default value used
```

Note that default values *work for any function*, not only for constructors

**Technique 3.** (when you need encapsulation) Use a factory method defined in a companion object

Sometimes you want your constructor private and only a factory method available to clients. For now this is only possible with a factory method defined in a **companion object**:

```
class C private (s: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun new(s: String) = C(s.length)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
val c = C.new("foo")
```

Comment: If secondary constructors are never supported, primary constructors should be renamed. ;)

Comment: Andrey Breslav, I believe it was a bad idea to drop support for secondary constructors in Kotlin since these constructors are necessary sometimes, especially when working with Java frameworks and extending Java classes. Hope you'll get them back soon.

Comment: That's funny: secondary constructors returned back :)

Comment: Secondary constructors were added in M11.

Comment: Is it still considered best practice to use static factory methods as described in Effective Java? Or is it not as necessary now? I imagine you will always want to use static factories if you ever foresee a need to control instances.

Comment: @ThomasN. You are really asking a new question, disguised as a comment.  Regardless, this is subjective.  Factories help when there is logic needed to assemble the class and you want to make that easier.  Or when it is dangerous to directly set values of the class in the constructor.  But I wouldn't call it a "best practice" for Kotlin.  "It depends" and is very opinionated answer.  I think this would be downvoted as a question because it isn't specific, no use case.  If you have a specific use case in mind, and you don't feel right about it being a constructor, ask that as a question.

Comment: "class object" has been renamed "companion object", as of M12. https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kotlin-m12-is-out/

Answer (score 65):

As the [documentation points](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html), you can use a secondary constructor this way

```
class GoogleMapsRestApiClient constructor(val baseUrl: String) {

    constructor() : this("https://api.whatever.com/")

}
```

Remember that you must extended the first constructor behavior.

Comment: Instead of extending first constructor directly from the second one can delegate to another secondary constructor, that already does it:

Comment: I think this one is better for current case:
`
class GoogleMapsRestApiClient constructor(val baseUrl: String = "https://api.whatever.com/") {

    //class body

}
`

Comment: It is! But that's not the context of the problem ^^ I could edi it with a better suggestion if you have one. Thanks for the shout out @AlexanderKrol

Answer (score 32):

for declaring a secondary constructor **Kotlin** just use the **constructor** keyword: like

this is a primary constructor:

```
class Person constructor(firstName: String) {

}
```

or

```
class Person(firstName: String) {

}
```

for the secondary constructor  code like this:

```
class Person(val name: String) {
    constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}
```

it is mandatory to call the primary **constructor** otherwise, the **compiler** will throw the following **error**

```
Primary constructor call expected
```

Answer (score 16):

Constructors with `init`:

```
class PhoneWatcher : TextWatcher {

    private val editText: EditText
    private val mask: String

    private var variable1: Boolean = false
    private var variable2: Boolean = false

    init {
        variable1 = false
        variable2 = false
    }

    constructor(editText: EditText) : this(editText, "##-###-###-####")

    constructor(editText: EditText, mask: String) {
        this.editText = editText
        this.mask = mask
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Too late to answer, but here is my humble contribution:)

As Kotlin supports default param value, (note: I want to use power of null) like this:

```
data class MyClass(val a: Int? = null, val b: String? = null, val c: Double? = null)
```

we dont need to have multiple constructor. but even if we want it, we can do it this way as well:

```
data class MyClass(val a: Int?, val b: String?, val c: Double?){
    constructor() : this(null,null,null)
    constructor(a : Int) : this(a,null,null)
    constructor(a : Int, b: String) : this(a,b,null)
}
```

we can instantiate this class in following ways:

```
println(MyClass().toString())
println(MyClass(1).toString())
println(MyClass(1,"String").toString())
println(MyClass(1,"String",0.5).toString())
```

and lets see the result as well:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**Custom View Example with Multiple Constructors in Android:**

```
class ShaderBackground : View {


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {

       // Init stuff here
        paint = Paint();
        paint.strokeWidth = 10f;
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE;

    }
```

Comment: Any shortcut  for making constructor for korlin files i tried ALT+INSERT but not showing any menu for generating constructor.
**can you please share the shortcut for generate constructor for kotlin POJO?**

Comment: @Arbaz.in  Generate a constructor for a class
On the Code menu, click Generate ⌘N.
In the Generate popup, click Constructor for Kotlin.
If the class contains fields, select the fields to be initialized by the constructor and click OK.

Answer (score 7):

You can define multiple constructors in Kotlin with `constructor` but you need to skip default constructor `class AuthLog(_data: String)`

```
class AuthLog {

    constructor(_data: String): this(_data, -1)

    constructor(_numberOfData: Int): this("From count ", _numberOfData)

    private constructor(_data: String, _numberOfData: Int)

}
```

[For more details see here](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/constructors)

**Update**

Now you can define default constructor

```
class AuthLog(_data: String, _numberOfData: Int) {

    constructor(_data: String): this(_data, -1) {
        //TODO: Add some code here if you want
    }

    constructor(_numberOfData: Int): this("From count", _numberOfData)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this question and I think there may be another technique which sounds even better than those proposed by Andrey.

```
class C(a: Int) {
    class object {
        fun invoke(name: String) = C(name.length)
    }        
}
```

That you can either write something like `val c:C = C(3)` or `val c:C = C("abc")`, because the `invoke` methods work kind of the same way the `apply` methods work in Scala.

**Update**

As of now, secondary constructors are already part of the language spec so this workaround shouldn't be used.

Comment: Secondary constructors (since M11) are better than this option.

Comment: I answered this before the release of M11, it's quite mean to downvote it, why don't you just try to edit the answer?

Comment: I can't edit the answer because my edit would not be inline with your answer.  I disagree that this should ever be suggested at all.  Deleting your answer would prevent my downvote.

Comment: Maybe it was a useful hack prior to M11 but it isn't now, and shouldn't be here.  If you leave it, you invite newer downvotes.  Keep your old posts updated and you won't run into this.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121351/312466

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet below should work

```
class  C(a:Int){
  constructor(s:String):this(s.length){..}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was a bit confused with most of the answers.
To make it easy to understand I am adding an example with more elements :

```
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   data class Response(val code: String) {
      var description: String? = null
      var value: String? = null

      constructor(code: String, description: String?) : this(code) {
          this.description = description
      }

      constructor(code: String, description: String?, value: String) : this(code, description) {
          this.value = value
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person(val name: String) {
    constructor(name: String, parent: Person) : this(name) {
        parent.children.add(this)
    }
}
```

you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

kotlin Secondary constructor example

```
class Person(name: String){
    var name=""
    var age=0

    constructor(age :Int,name : String)  : this(name){
        this.age=age
        this.name=name
    }
    fun display(){
        print("Kotlin Secondary constructor $name  , $age")
    }
}
```

main function

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){

    var objd=Person(25,"Deven")
    objd.display()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable 'internal' and then you can add multiple constructors inside single class like below. This will work flawlessly.

```kotlin
class AuthModel {
    var code: String? = null

    internal constructor(code: String?) {
        this.code = code
    }

    internal constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: This approach is the same like the java one. Thanks for the help.