# How to extend a class that has multiple constructors in Kotlin?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I am in the processing of learning Kotlin and ran into a problem I couldn't figure out.
I would like to extend the Java class `RuntimeException` in Kotlin and be able to use any one of three of its constructors, in different circumstances (based on what info I have at the time I want to throw an exception). In java my class would look like this:

```
public class PhotoLibException extends RuntimeException {

    public PhotoLibException(String message, RuntimeException ex) {
        super(message, ex);
    }

    public PhotoLibException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public PhotoLibException(RuntimeException ex) {
        super(ex);
    }
}
```

When I try to do this in Kotlin, I used this answer as a guide: [Kotlin secondary constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299525/kotlin-secondary-constructor) however, I had a problem trying to figure out how to invoke the appropriate super constructor correctly. For example, using functions seemed to be a good approach, like this:

```
fun PhotoLibException(message: String): PhotoLibException {
    val ex = null
    return PhotoLibException(message, ex)
}

fun PhotoLibException(ex: Exception): PhotoLibException {
    val message = ""
    return PhotoLibException(message, ex)
}

class PhotoLibException(message: String, ex: Exception?): RuntimeException(message, ex) {
}
```

However, in this Kotlin example above, I am always invoking the super constructor with two args, and not invoking the constructor most appropriate to the situation. So what I have above works, but doesn't do exactly what it would do in Java where a different constructor is invoked in each situation.
I also tried instantiating a new RuntimeException inside each fun above and casting it to PhotoLibException, but I wasn't allowed to do that.

Can anyone suggest how I would do this correctly in Kotlin?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

**Update**: Since M11 (0.11.*), you can use [*secondary constructors*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#secondary-constructors) to solve this problem:

```
class PhotoLibException : RuntimeException {
    constructor(message: String, ex: Exception?): super(message, ex) {}
    constructor(message: String): super(message) {}
    constructor(ex: Exception): super(ex) {}
}
```

Currently, there's no way to call different super-constructors in different context from the same class. It will be supported in the upcoming months, though.

Comment: Hi, does this solution hold good even today (as of kotlin 1.2.41)? I know it works but are there even simpler alternatives?

Comment: @Andrey Breslav How would I add a property to this? I.e. Say some boolean which is only PhotoLibException field passed in via constructor

Comment: Make sure your not initialising the any of the parent constructor on the same line as declaring the child class. Eg  
"class Child : Parent (- don't do this initialisation here-) "

Comment: Note that this only works if the class doesn't have a primary constructor - all constructors have to be "secondary". That's probably what @Niroshan meant.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/) annotation.

```
class PhotoLibException: RuntimeException {
   @JvmOverloads constructor(message: String, ex: Exception?)
}
```