# Create generic 2D array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

Suppose I have a generic class and I need a 2D array of generic type `T`. If I try the following

```
class Matrix<T>(width: Int, height: Int) {
    val data: Array<Array<T>> = Array(width, arrayOfNulls<T>(height))
}
```

the compiler will throw an error saying "*Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.*".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just because the syntax has moved on a bit, here's my take on it:

```
class Array2D<T> (val xSize: Int, val ySize: Int, val array: Array<Array<T>>) {

    companion object {

        inline operator fun <reified T> invoke() = Array2D(0, 0, Array(0, { emptyArray<T>() }))

        inline operator fun <reified T> invoke(xWidth: Int, yWidth: Int) =
            Array2D(xWidth, yWidth, Array(xWidth, { arrayOfNulls<T>(yWidth) }))

        inline operator fun <reified T> invoke(xWidth: Int, yWidth: Int, operator: (Int, Int) -> (T)): Array2D<T> {
            val array = Array(xWidth, {
                val x = it
                Array(yWidth, {operator(x, it)})})
            return Array2D(xWidth, yWidth, array)
        }
    }

    operator fun get(x: Int, y: Int): T {
        return array[x][y]
    }

    operator fun set(x: Int, y: Int, t: T) {
        array[x][y] = t
    }

    inline fun forEach(operation: (T) -> Unit) {
        array.forEach { it.forEach { operation.invoke(it) } }
    }

    inline fun forEachIndexed(operation: (x: Int, y: Int, T) -> Unit) {
        array.forEachIndexed { x, p -> p.forEachIndexed { y, t -> operation.invoke(x, y, t) } }
    }
}
```

This also allows you to create 2d arrays in a similar manner to 1d arrays, e.g. something like

```
val array2D = Array2D<String>(5, 5) { x, y -> "$x $y" }
```

and access/set contents with the indexing operator:

```
val xy = array2D[1, 2]
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it's a bit faulty. Because it's set array property via public constructor and set xSize and ySize at the same time. It could be misleading.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is calling `arrayOfNulls<T>(height)` with the non-reified type parameter T. But we also can't make `T` reified, the compiler will throw the following error: "*Only type parameters of inline functions can be reified*"

So that's what we're going to do. Instead of the constructor we use an inlined factory method:

```
class Matrix<T> private(width: Int, height: Int, arrayFactory: (Int) -> Array<T>) {

    class object {
        inline fun <reified T>invoke(width: Int, height: Int)
                = Matrix(width, height, { size -> arrayOfNulls<T>(size) })
    }

    val data: Array<Array<T>> = Array(width, { size -> arrayFactory(size) })
}
```

Notice, the constructor is now private, so calling `Matrix()` will correctly call the new invoke() method ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003889/615306)). Because the method is inlined, we can use [reified generics](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/12/m10-is-out/) which makes it possible to call `arrayOfNulls<T>`.