# Create a generic class with an array of type Comparable<T> in kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Inspired by [Create generic 2D array in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548647/create-generic-2d-array-in-kotlin), I have the following code that creates a generic class with an array of type T. However, once I add an upper bound, I get a compile error. Is there a way to do this?

```
//This code compiles:
class GenericClass<T> protected constructor(size : Int, arrayFactory: (Int) -> Array<T>) {
  companion object {
    inline fun <reified T> invoke(size : Int)
       = GenericClass(size, { size -> arrayOfNulls<T>(size) })
  }
  val array = arrayFactory(size)
}

//Compile errors:
class GenericClass<T : Comparator<T>> protected constructor(size : Int, arrayFactory: (Int) -> Array<T>) {
  companion object {
    inline fun <reified T : Comparator<T>> invoke(size : Int)
       = GenericClass(size, { size -> arrayOfNulls<T>(size) })
  }
  val array = arrayFactory(max)
}
```

The compile errors are:

- Type parameter bound for T in constructor GenericClass>(size: Int, arrayFactory: (Int) -> Array) is not satisfied: inferred type T? is not a subtype of Comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message while misleading does hint that it's about nullability constraints of your type arguments and parameters. Change the `GenericClass` constructor to allow for `null` inside `Array` like so:

```
class GenericClass<T : Comparator<T>> 
  protected constructor(size : Int, arrayFactory: (Int) -> Array<T?>) {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Comparator<T>> invoke(size : Int)
            = GenericClass(size, { size -> arrayOfNulls<T>(size) })
    }
    val array = arrayFactory(size)
}
```

[`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) as the name suggest creates array of given `size` filled with `null`s. Hence if you wish to use it the `arrayFactory` needs to accept it.