# Kotlin: Array of Generics

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

I'm writing a B-tree, which may have many keys in one node, and I have encountered a problem. When I create an array of **Ints** everything works fine:

```
class Node<K: Comparable<K>> (val t: Int) {
    val keys: Array<Int?> = Array<Int?> (t*2-1, {null})
}
```

But I want to create an array of Generics **Ks**:

```
class Node<K: Comparable<K>> (val t: Int) {
    val keys : Array<K?> = Array<K?> (t*2-1, {null})
}
```

In this case compiler throws this error message:

```
'Kotlin: Cannot use 'K' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.'
```

The question is **How to create an array of Generics?**

**UPD:** Thx for all the replies! It seems that *MutableList* is nice solution for my objective.

Comment: See: [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/529085/7079453)

Comment: Using an ArrayList instead of an array is a better option if you are not doing performance-critical operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create generic 2D array in Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548647/create-generic-2d-array-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `List<K>` instead, it doesn't require you to have `reified` types.

To use generic parameters with `Array<K>`, you need the generic parameter to be `reified` (so that you can get it's class)

You can't use `reified` with classes, only with functions, and the functions must be `inline`

So I'd suggest that you use a `class` as late as possible, with concrete or non-`reified` generic types.

Meanwhile, you can use functions like these

```
inline fun <reified K : Comparable<K>> computeKeys(t: Int): Array<K?> =
    Array(t * 2 - 1) { null }
```

Comment: Very true, use `List` instead of `Array` as much as possible. Arrays on JVM are outdated :(