# Initialize array with generic type in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, stack

I want to implement `stack` data structure using kotlin. I want to use `generic` array so as to create stack of any datatype. I am not sure how to initialize the array properly. It shows different kind of errors everytime. Also cannot figure out how to use `List<T>`. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
class StackADT<ANY>(var capacity: Int) {

    private var top = -1
    private val stack:  (generic type array)//NEED TO INITIALIZE PROPERLY HERE 

    fun push(element: ANY) {
        if (top == capacity)
            throw Exception("Overflow occurred in stack!!")
        stack[++top] = element
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin: Array of Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093498/kotlin-array-of-generics)

Answer (score 0):

```
class StackADT<T>(var capacity: Int) {

    private var top = -1
    private val stack: ArrayList<T> = ArrayList(capacity)

    fun push(element: T) {
        if (top == capacity)
            throw Exception("Overflow occurred in stack!!")
        top++
        stack.add(element)
    }
    ...
```

You can test here: [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/ByfNfnpON)

Another way:

```
var stack = arrayOfNulls<Any?>(capacity) as Array<T>
```

Comment: How to set the array with capacity in this?

Comment: Take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253626/3262021 (sorry I am writing from mobile so I can't test it)

Comment: I already had a look at it but could not figure out my problem

Comment: You can use ArrayList