# Overriding multiple versions of constructor in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view, constructor, android-custom-view

I was trying to implement `CustomView` in `Kotlin`, which is to be used both for programatically and for statically. Thus, I need to override both versions of constructors.

For programatically I use version,

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
   context: Context, 
) : View(context)
```

For statically I use version,

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context, 
  attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
) : View(context, attrs)
```

How can I change it for overriding multiple versions under same class which then I can instantiate from static views as well as programatically?

There are some post on constructors i.e. [Kotlin secondary constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19299525/1084174) which does not help for overriding multiple versions of constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work both programatically and statically :-

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

Programatically just call :-

```
CustomView(context) // passing other params to constructor is not mandatory..
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this code to recreate your issue:

`Test.java`:

```
public class Test {

    private int i ;
    private String name;

    public Test(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        name = "test";
    }

    public Test(int i, String name) {
        this.i = i;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`TestK.kt`:

```
class TestK : Test {
    constructor(i: Int, name: String): super(i, name)
    constructor(i: Int) : super(i)
}
```

As you can see, I'm overloading the parents constructor with different parameter amounts.

Comment: I can't comment on @santanu-sur answer, but in my opinion, it isn't exactly answering the question on how to overload several constructor. You're passing default value to the 3 arguments constructor, but that might not always be what we want. (Case of different constructor implementation.)